# How do I run the core workload against a table created in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, benchmarking, cassandra-2.0, ycsb

I am super new in benchmarking database. I got familiarity with YCSB tool a little bit, still studying a lot about it. I have downloaded YCSB latest version, and all the pre-requirement I need to benchmark Cassandra. I also have DataStax community installed in my machine. By using Cassandra CQL shell I have created a usertable with the following:

```
  create keyspace ycsb WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3 };
    use ycsb;
    create table usertable (id uuid, name varchar, email varchar, PRIMARY KEY (id, email));
```

Although in addition to Keyspace, I must create ColumnFamily- I don't know the query for that.

Besides having that table created, I can execute ycsb in command prompt:

```
    cd C:\ycsb
C:\Python27\python.exe bin\ycsb
```

Now the rest part remains unknown to me. How can I proceed now to load the workload into the database table and benchmark? I just want to do the basic benchmark with core workload, that means having the only *read, write, update, scan* metrics are enough for me.
I have searched a lot and trying to understand the Wiki instruction given in the YCSB GitHub page. But they are very confusing and there is no clear step to follow. If I go one step it navigates me to another link and makes my thought messy.
Please don't disappoint me, I will be very grateful to if someone out there can at least show me a single guideline.

Comment: will have better luck using cassandra-stress tool to benchmark different cassandra workloads. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress_t.html

Comment: Chris, thanks for your comment and suggestion. I actually need to benchmark with YCSB anyway. However I need to intstall DataStax for interacting with Cassandra Database. My question is, is DataStax supported with Windows-10? If so, after installing how do I know in which port it is running? And I only see the Cassandra CQL shell, where is the GUI interface of Cassandra? ...Looking forward your answer...

Comment: per https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/supportedPlatforms.html DataStax enterprise does not support windows. Apache Cassandra does support it well though if using newer (>3) versions. For a gui interface best bet is devcenter (http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-devcenter-and-development-tools)